# Is there an easy way to implement LINQ to object with a DataContext?

Tags: .net, linq, orm

I have a working LINQ to SQL model.  I want to be able to use the same model but with a connection to a DataSet object, instead of SQL Server.

I need to be able to query the model, modify fields, as well as do insert and delete operations.  Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

I noticed [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142762/is-there-a-datacontext-in-linq-to-entities-not-linq-to-sql) mentions a similar scenario, but I'm not sure if this applies to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [LINQ to DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977.aspx) directly but the LINQ to SQL query translator converts expression trees into SQL statements and that can't be changed.

For lists of inserts/updates/deletes for a given DataContext, you can call [**`DataContext.GetChangeSet()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.getchangeset.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You want a DataContext that is backed by a DataSet.  No, this does not exist unless you build it.