# Is DbContext the same as DataContext?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework-4

I'm following a tutorial by [Scott Gu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx) that refers to a class named DbContext. I can't find it on any namespace on framework 4 and it seems to me it was renamed from CT4 DbContext to .net4 System.Data.Linq.DataContext. Is my assumption correct?

Comment: did you download the CTP?  I believe it uses a namespace like System.Data.Entities.CTP or somesuch...

Comment: I have not. But I did find out about ObjectContext. Since this is for a production system, I can't use CTP.

Comment: NB I know its obvious but `System.Data.Linq.DataContext` is from LINQ To Sql and `DbContext` is from Entity Framework

Answer (score 88, accepted):

`DbContext` is a new class that was added in the recent separate download by EF team. It is currently not part of the core EF 4.0. However `DbContext` moving forward would be the preferred way to interact with EF.

So how is it different from `ObjectContext`? Well semantically they are exactly same but they reduced lot of extra noise that `ObjectContext` had. Like exposing a set required more work, for instance:

```
public ObjectSet<Customer> Customers
{
    get { return db.CreateObjectSet<Customer>(); }
}
```

With `DbContext` you can do:

```
public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
```

Basically on the `ObjectContext`, when you do dot (`.`), everything is just right there which makes the list pretty huge. What the EF team actually wanted to expose on `DbContext` are entities which are only specific to your domain and rest of ability of the framework is tucked in under different properties. It just makes the programming experience easier.

This means if you are using `ObjectContext` right now, with a little bit of code, you can easily move to `DbContext`.

Comment: Any idea on when it will be merged into the main framework branch?

Comment: EF 4.1 has been released as of Apr 11. 2011. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/04/11/ef-4-1-released.aspx for details.

Comment: Doesn't this tie you to EF for you whole project, say it you had a Business Layer?

Comment: The question was `is DbContext the same as DataContext?` ... i am confused .. so now the question `is ObjectContext is same as DataContext?`

Comment: @Moumit check my answer if it is still actual :)

Answer (score 14):

It's a bit too late, but for the googlers. `DbContext` is used for `EF` (*EntityFramework*) and `DataContext` is used for `L2S` (*LINQ To SQL*).

Answer (score 0):

### `DbContext`

- one of *EntityFramework's* classes.
- represents a Session between your program & a Database.
- allows your program to send & retrieve data to/from a Database.

### `DataContext`

- a class you create in your program that inherits from `DbContext`.
- use `DataContext` to retrieve or update data locally in your program.
- then push changes (using methods from the inherited `DbContext`) to the actual Database to update it.

Comment: `System.Data.Linq.DataContext` is the old wrapper from LINQ-to-SQL.  If you write your own EntityFramework DbContext wrapper (which you really don't need to do 99% of the time), you should probably give it a different name...