# entity framework 4.1 objectContext vs dbContext

Tags: entity-framework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ADO.NET DbContext Generator vs. ADO.NET Poco Entity Generator (ObjectContext)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340990/ado-net-dbcontext-generator-vs-ado-net-poco-entity-generator-objectcontext)

Should I use ObjectContext or DbContext? What's the best way?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471455/is-dbcontext-the-same-as-datacontext

Comment: @all instead of upvoting on possible duplicate suggestions, one should vote to close if you agree!

Answer (score 26):

I am currently using DbContext in a Database first situation and it is working fine. DbContext is NOT only for Code First development.

DbContext acts like a wrapper around the ObjectContext. Julie Lerman has a nice explanation, how you can access the ObjectContext that is inside of DbContext [here](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/accessing-objectcontext-features-from-ef-4-1-dbcontext/). So if you decide to use DbContext, you can still solve things with ObjectContext if you need to.

DbContext simplifies common tasks. One example is the Find() method.

```
Product p = db.Products.Find(id);
```

Answer (score 16):

ObjectContext for version 4.0 when using a designer generated model and DbContext with a 4.1 Code First model.

Comment: -1 If this question wasnt so dramatically over-voted, I'd just comment, 'why ? Please provide some justification'

Answer (score 2):

It seems like when you use the designer generated model it automatically defaults to ObjectContext anyway

Comment: Only if you do not add another Code Generation Item.

Comment: Add a DbContext Generator first and your model will use DbContext.  If you first add POCO Entity Generator, then your entities will derive from ObjectContext.