# 'ObjectContext' vs 'DbContext' in Entity Framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework, dbcontext, objectcontext

I'm using the `DbContext` class within code that I am creating that is based on the Generic Repositories and Unit of Work design patterns. (I am following the guidance [here](http://elegantcode.com/2009/12/15/entity-framework-ef4-generic-repository-and-unit-of-work-prototype/).) While working on this project I have encountered the `ObjectContext` class.

I've read quite a number of posts that discuss **`ObjectContext` vs. `DbContext`**. While some of what I've read makes sense, I still don't have a complete understanding of the differences and this leaves me wondering about my current implementation. Should I be using `DbContext`, `ObjectContext` or both? Is using one of these now considered an anti-pattern?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is DbContext the same as DataContext?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471455/is-dbcontext-the-same-as-datacontext)

Comment: This is not a Decorator its a Composite pattern

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`DbContext` is just a wrapper around `ObjectContext`.

`DbContext` is just a set of APIs that are easier to use than the APIs exposed by `ObjectContext`.

Anyway, [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MassimilianoPeluso-Pelusoftlimited.PeluSoftEFRepository) you'll find a very simple Visual Studio template that uses the Repository Pattern and the Entity Framework.

Comment: check this [article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/objectcontext-vs-dbcontext/) for more

Answer (score -1):

From [ObjectContext VS DBContext.](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/objectcontext-vs-dbcontext/)

Dbcontext can be defined as a lightweight version of the ObjectContext or we can say Dbcontext is a wrapper of ObjectContext and exposes only the common features that are really required in programming.
We can also get a reference to the ObjectContext from then DbContext to use those features that are only supported in ObjectContext.

The following code could help to get an ObjectContext Object from an existing DbContext Object.

```
public class EntityDBContext: DbContext, IObjectContextAdapter
{
   ObjectContext IObjectContextAdapter.ObjectContext
   {
        get
        {
              var objectContext = (this as IObjectContextAdapter)
              if(objectContext != null)
                return (this as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;
              else
                return null;
        }
   }
}
```

Finally, DbContext is not a replacement of ObjectContext, but it is a simple alternative that builds on ObjectContext.

Comment: this one throws StackOwerflowException. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms182153.aspx

Answer (score -2):

We can cast a DBContext to type ObjectContext

```
public class MyContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
   //other dbsets, ctor etc.

    public ObjectContext ObjectContext()
    {
        return (this as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;
    }
}
```