# Is it always better to use 'DbContext' instead of 'ObjectContext'?

Tags: dbcontext, entity-framework-4.3, objectcontext

I just downloaded `EntityFramework.dll v4.3`. I've found a number of questions that compare `DbContext` vs. `ObjectContext`. But most of these are from 2010, or early 2011.

I'd like to read more on the subject. Specifically, are there any books on `DbContext` I can get my hands on? I also want to know, as of today, what are the limitations of `DbContext` when comparing it to its older brother the `ObjectContext`?

I realize that `DbContext` is more compact in that it exposes fewer properties. This suggests to me that I should migrate from `ObjectContext`. But, if I do this migration, will I give up any capabilities? For example, I've read that `DbContext` doesn't have the STE (Self-tracking entities) capability. Does this still hold true and is it a concern?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['ObjectContext' vs 'DbContext' in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9176967/objectcontext-vs-dbcontext-in-entity-framework)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> I'd like to read more on the subject. Specifically, are there any
>   books on `DbContext` I can get my hands on?

Your question does not start off well because a single Google query will give you an answer for this. There is an [excellent book about DbContext](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449312969) itself — it doesn't contain anything about the Code First approach, but I guess that is really not the point of your question.

> I've found a number of questions that compare `DbContext` vs.
>   `ObjectContext`. But most of these are from 2010, or early 2011.

If you just want to replace `ObjectContext` + EDMX with `DbContext` + EDMX, the comparison is still the same. `DbContext` is a wrapper around `ObjectContext` and its feature set didn't grow up except with respect to those features related to Code First and Migrations.

> I realize that `DbContext` is more compact in that it exposes fewer
>   properties. This suggests to me that I should migrate from
>   `ObjectContext`.

Yes, it is more compact and it simplifies most common tasks that you have to do with the context. For more complex tasks, you can still convert a `DbContext` instance to an `ObjectContext` instance through `IObjectContextAdapter`.

> But, if I do this migration, will I give up any capabilities? For
>   example, I've read that `DbContext` doesn't have the STE (Self-tracking
>   entities) capability. Does this still hold true and is it a concern?

STE was created for `ObjectContext` and I don't think it was ported to `DbContext`, but you can try to implement this capability yourself.

STEs are just a template with an idea to solve some problem. It appeared as a good theoretical solution but it wasn't very well accepted by the developer community because the solution is not very good for real world scenarios. It is also the reason why other more important features are being developed instead of improving or porting the template.

Comment: Regarding STEs: "The Entity Framework team hasn't made any significant updates to the Self-Tracking Entities template since it was first released.  They are recommending that developers look at using WCF Data Services as a more robust and complete solution." (p.76 from Julia Lerman's _DbContext_)