# Do ObjectContext and ObjectSet offer advantages over DbContext and DbSet?

Tags: entity-framework, objectset, dbset

I am currently finalizing the architecture of my new application that will be using Entity Framework as its ORM. However, I am a little bit confused with respect to whether I should go with the default option (`DbSet` and `DbContext`), or use a "tricky" option (`ObjectSet` and `ObjectContext`)? Do the latter classes offer advantages over the default classes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it always better to use 'DbContext' instead of 'ObjectContext'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10475306/is-it-always-better-to-use-dbcontext-instead-of-objectcontext)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several posts on this topic which go into detail about your question, and I'm sure you will find helpful:

[On DbContext, is it strictly better than ObjectContext?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10475306/on-dbcontext-is-it-strictly-better-than-objectcontext)

[entity framework 4.1 objectContext vs dbContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376368/entity-framework-4-1-objectcontext-vs-dbcontext)

[ObjectContext vs DbContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9176967/objectcontext-vs-dbcontext)

[difference between DBContext and Object context in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12531270/difference-between-dbcontext-and-object-context-in-entity-framework)

Answer (score 2):

Just summarization. *DbContext* is a wrapper around the *ObjectContext*. You can also access *ObjectContext* by *DbContext* if you need. *ObjectContext* came with EF4 and *DbContext* with EF4.1. Basically both contexts are almost same. *DbContext* simplifies many things. Moreover *DbContext* doesn't contains hundreds of properties like *ObjectContext* - it is more clear and compact.