# Linqpad - Save Changes works without Linq To Entiies Database Context

Tags: c#, linq, linqpad

I am learning how to use Linqpad.  Please see the code below (Linqpad C# Program):

```
//UPDATE (c# Porgram)
void Main()
{
    var v1 = Vendors.Single(x => x.BusinessEntityID == 1492);
    v1.Name = "Hello"; //Australia Bike Retailer
    SaveChanges();
}
```

It works as I would expect.  I have two questions:

```
1) How does it work without the Linq To Entities Database context?
2) How would I delete v1?
```

**Update**

I have tried this following on from an answer below:

[image]

Comment: maybe `this` is bound to your DB context? `(this == Util.CurrentDataContext).Dump();`

Comment: @Jens Kloster you are right, I wil delete my post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you write in LinqPad is actually *inside* your DB context.
Then you [specified the connection](https://www.linqpad.net/EntityFramework.aspx), you were asked to point to the assembly that holds your DB Context. 
That is how LinqPad knows.

To delete V1 do as you normally would:

```
Vendors.Delete(v1);
SaveChanges();
```

**UPDATE**
Dependending on which [context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9176967/objectcontext-vs-dbcontext) you use, it could be:

```
Venders.Delete(v1);
```

or

```
Vendors.Remove(v1);
```

Comment: I have made a change to my question.  I get an error when I do this.

Comment: I am using a dbContext so have to use: Remove.  Thanks for that. What is the method name for an insert? (for an upvote).

Comment: @w0051977 I would guess **.Add(v1)**. See this site for good tutorials: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/add-entity-using-dbcontext.aspx