# Problems adding object to database in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, db2

I have the following code trying to add an object to the database:

```
public static void saveAudit(List<AUDIT> audit)
{
 Entities dao = new Entities();

 foreach (CMUAUDIT a in audit)
 {
    dao.CMUAUDITs.AddObject(a);
 }

 dao.SaveChanges();
}
```

However I get the error message:

> "...does not contain a definition for 'AddObject' and no extension
>   method 'AddObject' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

I've done some searching, and there is mention of the primary key having something to do with it. Any suggestions?

I'm using a DB2 database if that makes any difference?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`...System.Data.Entity.DbSet...`: Apparently your class `Entities` is derived from `DbContext` and not `ObjectContext`. `CMUAUDITs` will be a `DbSet<T>` (and not an `ObjectSet<T>`) in this case. The correct method to add an entity to a `DbSet<T>` is:

```
dao.CMUAUDITs.Add(a);
```

`AddObject` is only available for an `ObjectSet<T>`.

Comment: what is the difference between dbcontext and objectcontext?

Comment: @stats101: `DbContext` is a wrapper around `ObjectContext` with a simplified API. It also contains the "Code First" development strategy. It is recommended to prefer `DbContext` because it is easier to use and work with - unless you have some advanced requirements which are not available with `DbContext` like mapping to Stored Procedures. Links: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3473323/270591 and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/04/11/ef-4-1-released.aspx