# Insert or Update Entity Framework Many-to-Many

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, relational-database

I am trying to update a join table using Entity Framework that has the following design 
[image]

I am trying the following piece of code but it doesn't update the join table DeliveryDayBrands, please tell me what I am doing wrong. Thanks.

```
public async Task<Brand> Update(Brand brand, IEnumerable<int> SelectedDeliveryDays)
    {

        using (var dc = DataContext())
        {
            foreach (int deliveryDayId in SelectedDeliveryDays)
            {
                DeliveryDay deliveryDay = new DeliveryDay();
                deliveryDay = dc.DeliveryDays.FirstOrDefault(d => d.DeliveryDayId == deliveryDayId);


                brand.DeliveryDays.Add(deliveryDay);

            }

            dc.SetModified(brand);
            await dc.SaveChangesAsync();
            return brand;
        }
    }
```

Comment: does `dc.SetModified(brand);` set it's state to `EntityState.Modified`?

Comment: @Baksteen yes it does

Comment: In my experience, Entity Framework uses `Entry(brand).State = EntityState.Modified` of the `DbContext` class, instead of `DataContext`.

Comment: it does update the Brand entity but doesn't insert records in the DeliveryDayBrands for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to add some already existing DeliveryDays to a Brand. You don't need to re-add it to the database, as doing so will result in creating duplicates.

Also, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43798625/4095674), `DataContext` is used for LINQ to SQL. The answer says you need to use the `DbContext` class to talk to Entity Framework.

I suggest you try to fetch the connection string to the database from your `web.config` (or elsewhere), and then try the following:

```
public async Task<Brand> Update(Brand brand, IEnumerable<int> SelectedDeliveryDays)
{
    using (var context = new DbContext([insert connectionString to database here]))
    {
        foreach (int deliveryDayId in SelectedDeliveryDays)
        {
            DeliveryDay deliveryDay = context.DeliveryDays.FirstOrDefault(
               d => d.DeliveryDayId == deliveryDayId);

            deliveryDay.Brands.Add(brand);
            brand.DeliveryDays.Add(deliveryDay)

            // You could also use your custom SetModified method.
            context.Entry(brand).State = EntityState.Modified;
            context.Entry(deliveryDay).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }            

        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return brand;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am setting the state to modified using set modified how does that differ 
public void SetModified(object entity)
        {
            Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }

Comment: It doesn't.. use whatever way you prefer :) What matters is the type of class you're using. You should use `DbContext` instead of `DataContext`

Comment: Please see the edit in your answer it inserts duplicates when doing so

Comment: `DeliveryDay deliveryDay = new DeliveryDay();` - you don't have to "initialize" the value when you are re-assigning it in the next line. You are just creating and abandoning an extra object that needs to be garbage-collected

Comment: I think I understand your situation better now. I've updated my answer yet again.